# Download the images from the folder of the remote database and print them in a GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-asynctask

The following code does not print the images  downloaded from database at the Activity.
I do not understand where I'm wrong, does not crash.

Thank you in advance to those who help me!

MainActivity.java:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
//ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i("MainActivity", "dopo xml");

    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
   //imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    final ArrayAdapter<DatiServer> adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("MainActivity", "connection");

    new Connection(adapter).execute();


}
```

Connection.java:

```
public final class Connection extends AsyncTask< Void, DatiServer, Void> {


JSONArray jArray;
String dati = null;

private final ArrayAdapter<DatiServer> adapter;


public Connection (ArrayAdapter<DatiServer> adapter)
{
    this.adapter = adapter;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Log.i("MainActivity", "diInBackground");

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.site.it/images/utente_img.php");      
    try {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        Log.d("Connection","vaolori di response: " + response);
        dati = leggiDati(response);
        Log.d("Connection","vaolori di dati dopo chiamata leggiDati: " + dati);
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Connection", "errore connessione", e);
    }

    Log.d("Connection","vaolori di dati dopo try http: " + dati);
    try{ 
        Log.i("Connection", "Json");
        Log.d("Connection","vaolori di dati che vanno dell'oggetto json: " + dati);
        Log.i("Connection", "JSONObject");
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(dati);
        Log.d("Connection","vaolori jArray: " + jArray);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            Log.d("Connection", "jArray i " + jArray.length());
            DatiServer datiserver = new DatiServer();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            datiserver.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("immagine"));
            publishProgress(datiserver);
            }
     }

    catch (JSONException ignored)
    {
    }
    return null;

}


private String leggiDati(HttpResponse response) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "leggiDati");

    Log.d("Log_tag","vaolori di dati: " + response);

    InputStream content = null;
    try {
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numRead = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while((numRead=content.read(buffer))!=-1){
            baos.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        Log.i("Dopo inputStream", "fine while leggi dati " + baos);
        return new String(baos.toByteArray());
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return "errore!!";
    }
}



protected void onProgressUpdate(DatiServer... values)
{

    Log.i("Connection", "onProgressUpdate");

    for (DatiServer datiserver : values)
    {
        Log.i("Connection", "onProgressUpdate " + datiserver);

        adapter.add(datiserver);
    }
}
```

}

DatiServer.java

```
public class DatiServer {

private String ImageUrl;

public String getImageUrl()
{
    Log.i("DatiServer", "getImageUrl()");
    Log.d("DatiServer", "valore getImageUrl " + ImageUrl );
    return ImageUrl;
}

public String getTesto()
{
    Log.i("DatiServer", "getImageUrl()");
    Log.d("DatiServer", "valore getImageUrl " + ImageUrl );
    return ImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String ImageUrl)
{
    Log.i("DatiServer", "setImageUrl");
    this.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;
    Log.d("DatiServer", "valore setImageUrl " + ImageUrl );

}
```

}

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DatiServer>
```

{

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context)
{
    super(context, 0, new ArrayList<DatiServer>());
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    Log.i ("ImageAdapter", "dentro getView()");


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (imageView == null)
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        Log.i ("ImageAdapter", "imageView(getContext()) " + imageView);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        //imageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //imageView.setLines(1);
    }
    DatiServer datiserver  = getItem(position);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(downloadBitmap(datiserver.getImageUrl()));
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
    Log.i ("ImageAdapter", "imageView " + imageView);

    return imageView;


}

private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String fileUrl)
{

    Log.i ("ImageAdapter", "dentro downloadBitmap fileUrl " + fileUrl);

    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(fileUrl).openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (is != null)
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

This is file di log:

```
 11-28 14:04:42.134: I/MainActivity(896): dopo xml
 11-28 14:04:42.144: I/MainActivity(896): connection
 11-28 14:04:42.197: I/MainActivity(896): diInBackground
 11-28 14:04:42.534: I/Choreographer(896): Skipped 172 frames!  The application may be    doing too much work on its main thread.
 11-28 14:04:42.544: D/gralloc_goldfish(896): Emulator without GPU emulation det ected.
 11-28 14:04:42.764: I/Choreographer(896): Skipped 141 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 11-28 14:04:43.644: D/Connection(896): vaolori di response:       org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40d2d900
 11-28 14:04:43.644: I/MainActivity(896): leggiDati
 11-28 14:04:43.644: D/Log_tag(896): vaolori di dati: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@40d2d900
 11-28 14:04:43.684: I/Dopo inputStream(896): fine while leggi dati 
 11-28 14:04:43.684: I/Dopo inputStream(896): [{"immagine":"images\/img1.jpeg" }]
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): vaolori di dati dopo chiamata leggiDati: 
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): [{"immagine":"images\/img1.jpeg"}]
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): vaolori di dati dopo try http: 
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): [{"immagine":"images\/img1.jpeg"}]
 11-28 14:04:43.684: I/Connection(896): Json
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): vaolori di dati che vanno dell'oggetto json: 
 11-28 14:04:43.684: D/Connection(896): [{"immagine":"images\/img1.jpeg"}]
 11-28 14:04:43.684: I/Connection(896): JSONObject
 11-28 14:04:43.704: D/Connection(896): vaolori jArray:  [{"immagine":"images\/img1.jpeg"}]
 11-28 14:04:43.714: D/Connection(896): jArray i 1
 11-28 14:04:43.714: I/DatiServer(896): setImageUrl
 11-28 14:04:43.724: D/DatiServer(896): valore setImageUrl images/img1.jpeg
 11-28 14:04:43.724: I/Connection(896): onProgressUpdate
 11-28 14:04:43.724: I/Connection(896): onProgressUpdate  it.wss.prova.DatiServer@40d31e80
 11-28 14:04:43.764: I/ImageAdapter(896): dentro getView()
 11-28 14:04:43.774: I/ImageAdapter(896): imageView(getContext()) android.widget.ImageView{40d32768 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-0,0}
 11-28 14:04:43.774: I/DatiServer(896): getImageUrl()
 11-28 14:04:43.774: D/DatiServer(896): valore getImageUrl images/img1.jpeg
 11-28 14:04:43.784: I/ImageAdapter(896): dentro downloadBitmap fileUrl images/img1.jpeg
 11-28 14:04:43.794: I/ImageAdapter(896): imageView android.widget.ImageView{40d32768 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
 11-28 14:04:43.814: I/ImageAdapter(896): dentro getView()
 11-28 14:04:43.814: I/DatiServer(896): getImageUrl()
 11-28 14:04:43.814: D/DatiServer(896): valore getImageUrl images/img1.jpeg
 11-28 14:04:43.814: I/ImageAdapter(896): dentro downloadBitmap fileUrl  images/img1.jpeg
 11-28 14:04:43.824: I/ImageAdapter(896): imageView android.widget.ImageView{40d32768 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
 11-28 14:33:37.945: D/dalvikvm(896): GC_CONCURRENT freed 134K, 10% free 2617K/2892K, paused 8ms+5ms, total 85ms
```